# If a chaincode invocation both queries and updates private data, the proposal request will return an error. WHY?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

> Chaincode that executes range or rich JSON queries and updates data in
>   a single transaction is not supported, as the query results cannot be
>   validated on the peers that don’t have access to the private data, or
>   on peers that are missing the private data that they have access to.
>   If a chaincode invocation both queries and updates private data, the
>   proposal request will return an error. If your application can
>   tolerate result set changes between chaincode execution and
>   validation/commit time, then you could call one chaincode function to
>   perform the query, and then call a second chaincode function to make
>   the updates. Note that calls to GetPrivateData() to retrieve
>   individual keys can be made in the same transaction as
>   PutPrivateData() calls, since all peers can validate key reads based
>   on the hashed key version.
>   [Find Link Here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data-arch.html#querying-private-data)

I came across this small paragraph related to `limitation of querying Private Data` in fabric. I am pretty much new to private data concept.

What I understood is as follow,

- CC invocation requiring 
  Range or rich JSON queries AND update both, to private data causes proposal to return error.
- It's better to,  call one chaincode function to perform the query, and then call a second chaincode function to make the updates
- Normally, `GetPrivateData()` to retrieve individual keys can be made in the same transaction as `PutPrivateData()` calls, since all peers can validate key reads based on the hashed key version.

Is my understanding correct ? 
If yes then why is it so for private data?
If no then please give me wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all - rich queries are never re-executed upon commit anyway, be it private data or not private data.

Now, as for range queries - remember that range queries are all about the assumption that keys have an alphabetical order between them.

However, a transaction needs to pass MVCC checks regardless of the peer has the private data or not, but if the peer doesn't have the private data then it **only sees hashes**, (not the real key names) and hashes are not sorted alphabetically - hence it cannot validate that the range query simulation is not stale.

Comment: Thanks, @yacovm, I think you answered it just what I needed. I need a little more digging I thing on how rich and range queries work.